# How can baseboards be attached to a plaster-on-masonry wall?

Tags: baseboard, masonry

The walls on the sides and back of my fireplace are plaster on masonry. How can I attach baseboards to these walls? I tried bonding with HMA but eventually that just peels the paint off.

Comment: HMA? Do you mean [hot glue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot-melt_adhesive)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paint difficulties can be resolved by scraping and priming with a shellac or oil based primed.  I prefer the polyurethane based construction adhesives for strength and toughness.  Their down side is cure time (overnight)

Another scheme would be to cut back the plaster to 75% of the baseboard height with a diamond blade in an angle grinder (yes, very messy: floor to ceiling tarping, shop vac.. ) Then place 1x or thicker wood and blue screw (one brand of masonry screws are blue and need only a pilot hole (also comes in counter sinkable flat heads))(Tapcon brand, GRK and Spax are also good) it to masonry.  Overfill with setting joint compound to flush surface.  Nail baseboard normally.

[image]  [image]

Not afflliated with either company.  Have used both.

Comment: PL Premium is like the duct tape of the adhesive world. (i.e. I use it for everything). +1 for polyurethane!

Comment: What does "*blue screw it to masonry*" mean?  Also, pictures make everything better ;)

Comment: I agree with everything here - except I would definitely apply pressure to the baseboards until they cured - at least 12 hours.

Answer (score 6):

If by *HMA* you mean [Hot-Melt Adhesive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot-melt_adhesive), that stuff is for arts & crafts, not construction.

[image: Hot Glue gun]

You should be using construction adhesive.

[LOCTITE®](http://www.loctiteproducts.com/p/12/5/pg_ca_panel_clr/overview/Loctite-Power-Grab-Molding-&-Paneling-Clear-Construction-Adhesive.htm), [LIQUID NAILS®](http://www.liquidnails.com/products/bonding-adhesive-LN910), [DAP®](http://www.dap.com/product_details.aspx?BrandID=83&SubcatID=11), and possibly other adhesive manufacturers offer a molding adhesive.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If HMA sticks the baseboard to the paint instead of the wall, why would these products behave differently?

Comment: Not sure, I'm not a chemist. All I know is hot glue hardens and becomes brittle over time, where as construction adhesive does not.

Comment: It could be the hot glue interacts with the paint in a strange way. I do know I've used Liquid Nails on baseboard in a similar situation (drywall over [one course concrete blocks](http://i.imgur.com/HpZDATi.jpg) - in case you're wondering why I didn't use strapping) and never had a problem for the 4+ years I lived in the house. I'd also suggest doing this with a proper construction adhesive, and if there's still a problem, come ask about that.

Comment: Thanks for your opinions. I've had only terrible experiences with construction adhesive so I'd like another option. In fact, my experience is the opposite: I've seen EVA (same substance as HMA) stay pliable after 30 years of outdoor exposure in direct sunlight and construction adhesive hard and brittle after <5 years indoors protected between layers of construction materials.

Comment: I agree with using adhesive designed for the job. Test some different products with scrap if you are concerned about performance.